# Passing object with predefined props to class constructor es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to pass to my class constructor an object with predefined properties.

like this

```
class Test {

constructor({
    a = "test a",
    b = "test b"
    }) {

    }
}
```

P.S. I know how to define properties of objects. I want to know how to predefine properties.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes There's an example right at the top of the page.

Comment: Did you tried to read my question?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. That's not even correct JSON formatting for the object. Nor is it how you accept arguments to any JavaScript function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters
read the second example from top.

Comment: I can pass predefined variable to function.but how can i pass an object with predefined properties

Comment: You mean like a CONSTRUCTOR? See Titus' answer below for a start...

Comment: put OBJECT ,not variables like 
`someFunc(a='asd',b='dsa');`
in arguments with predefined props. I want to see how you will do that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you want to pass one object to the constructor and have its properties assigned to single keys of the class. You can use destructuring for that this way:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor({a,b} = {a:1,b:2}) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

Be aware that this is not safe for partially filled objects:

```
var instance = new MyClass({a:3});
// instance.b == undefined
```

Handling this could be done like so:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor({a=1,b=2} = {}) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

Which results in:

```
var instance = new MyClass({a:3});
// instance.a == 3
// instance.b == 2
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i know about destructing...and my problem is partially filled objects..i want that if i will change only `a` - prop other prop `b` must stay predefined..

Comment: edited answer to allow partial objects. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks @loganfsmyth for simplification.

Comment: Having the extra `{a,b}` in there would be a TDZ error :)

Comment: I tested it with babel and it worked fine. Just read that there is some difference in real es6 and transpiled versions. So thanks for that pointer! What about then just using `constructor({a=1,b=2})` alone? Doesn't that lead to the same result?

Comment: @AndreasJägle Perfect! Can I also pass the arguments to super somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to pass the constructor and object during instantiation:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(obj){
      this.a = obj.a;
      this.b = obj.b;
     }
  };

const obj = {
 a: 'value',
 b: 'value'
};

const newtTest = new Test(obj);
```

Comment: But it will throw a TypeError if you will not pass an object during instantiation. And the main question was how i will pass predefined props if i will handle an undefined instead object or if some props will be skipped.

Comment: Hence the stipulation to pass an object to the constructor during class instantiation. The question was how to pass the constructor and object with predefined properties.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, there's an example right at the top of the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

```
class Test {
    constructor(/* put arguments here if you want to pass any */){
        //Pre-define a and b for any new instance of class Test
        this.a = "test a";
        this.b = "test b";
    }
}
```

Comment: put object in arguments with predefined props

Comment: `constructor(obj) { this.a = obj.a; this.b = obj.b; }` The object you pass in has the properties, not the definition inside the constructor's parameter list.

Comment: so i have to define it some where.but what about predefined object in constructor? like this 

`constructor({a:'asdasd',b:'dsadsa'}){...}`

Comment: ...that's what my answer does. You're using the wrong syntax.